# Eclipse is building project without errors, but reporting unresolved inclusions

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I think my Eclipse got updated and since then my projects build sucessfully without errors but the IDE is reporting *unresolved inclusion* on `stdbool.h,stack.h and list.h`:

[image]

Eclipse version:

Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)

Build id: 20191212-1212

I am using CMake to build the project and my CMakeList.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

project (ullman)


find_package( OpenCL REQUIRED )

include_directories(parser ullman gpu ${OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})



add_executable(ullman entryPoint.cpp 
parser/edgeParser.cpp parser/edgeParser.h 
ullman/ullmanSeq.cpp ullman/ullmanSeq.h 
gpu/gpuRefinement.cpp gpu/gpuRefinement.h
ullman/ullmanGPU.cpp ullman/ullmanGPU.h )

target_link_libraries(ullman ${OpenCL_LIBRARIES})
```

I guess something got messed up during the update and I cant seem to find how to fix it. I have tried cleaning the project and rebuilding the index but nothing works.

EDIT:
I checked the project settings as suggested in the comments but all options I see under the mentioned tab are:
[image]

Comment: Unrelated: Rather than using the C headers, include the C++ versions. Eg: instead of stdio.h, use cstdio. By the way, are you sure you want to use C-style IO in a C++ program?

Comment: It is a goup school project and the other guy wanted to use some C++ libraries in a otherwise C program. I have tried your sugestion to replace C headers but the problem persists.

Comment: Eclipse's CODAN tool is pretty easy to fool. Make sure all Eclipse knows all of the appropriate paths and knows that it's not supposed to build against C89.

Comment: Where do I acces the settings to specifiy the compiler? I cant seem to find them :/

Comment: Eclipse should detect all this for you, but it looks like it's locked onto a really old C (might be something useful to see in project->properties->C/C++ Build->Environment) compiler. Includes are added manually in project->properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols.

Comment: Ah yes I need to go under my build configuration. That solved the issue. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)